# How to display text in html/javascript/jQuery identical in firefox and explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a question regarding html, javascript and/or jQuery. I do not have any experience in the latter two techniques.

The following  code pieces show the text 'Browse' as a single word on a browser. On firefox (30.0) this text is shown as an underlined link, while on the Windows Explorer (Version 11) the underline is missing. How must I change the code to get the text underlined as well in the Windows Explorer?

The main html code is here:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.fileinput.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fileinput.js"></script>
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.browse').customFileInput().change(function(){ });
        $('.customfile-button').wrap('<a href="#">');
        $('.browse').each(function(){
            $('.customfile-feedback', $(this).parent()).text('');
            $('.customfile-button', $(this).parent()).text("Browse");
        });
    });
</script>  

<input type="file"
       class="browse "
       accept="audio/*"
       width="100%">

</body>
</html>
```

Internally, it uses `jquery-1.4.4` and a `fileinput` module [from here](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Custom-File-Input/blob/master/js/jQuery.fileinput.js). The content of `jquery.fileinput.css` is as follows:

```
.customfile-input {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index: 999;
}

.customfile {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.customfile-disabled {
    opacity: .5;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: default;
}

.customfile-feedback {
    display: block;
}

.customfile-button {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Again, I want to change the code, styles, scripts, whatever, to render the text 'Browse' as an underlined 'link' in both browsers (firefox, explorer).

Comment: $('.customfile-button', $(this).parent()).text("Browse").addClass('underline'); In CSS use .underline{text-decoration:underline;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you class .customfile-button, set the text-decoration to underline, it should do the job:

```
.customfile-button {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! It really seems to do the job.